# how to split one line with customized separator and assign to variables in BASH?

Tags: bash, awk, eval

First I was using IFS and read, but then I found -- IFS can only support single character as separator and sometimes I need a string to be the separator.
Then, I was thinking maybe use awk and eval can do it. So I have a try --

```
eisen@PVGN34701109A:/tmp> cat file1
hah   a#$hehe#$hoho
eisen@PVGN34701109A:/tmp> cat t2.sh
#!/bin/bash
eval $(awk -F'#\\\$' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)   print "VAR"i"='\''"$i"'\''"}'  file1)
echo "VAR1=  ${VAR1}"
echo "VAR2=  ${VAR2}"
echo "VAR3=  ${VAR3}"
eisen@PVGN34701109A:/tmp> ./t2.sh
awk: warning: escape sequence `\$' treated as plain `$'
VAR1=  hah a
VAR2=  hehe
VAR3=  hoho
```

At first, I think it's fine. But immediately I found the issue -- in file1, the first value should be "hah   a" -- there's 3 space inside, But after awk and eval -- there's only one space left...
Then I tested with awk and eval individually, I found it's due to the eval will "eat" some space--

```
eisen@PVGN34701109A:/tmp> eval "VAR1='hah   a'";echo $VAR1
hah a
eisen@PVGN34701109A:/tmp> eval 'VAR1="hah   a"';echo $VAR1
hah a
```

I can't find solution myself. Please kind help and if there's any other better way to split one line and assign to variables in BASH, please share your idea. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using shell arrays for storing individual field values and slightly different `awk` for this:

```bash
IFS=$'\03' read -ra arr < <(awk -F'#\\$' -v OFS='\03' '{$1=$1}1' file)

# check array content
declare -p arr

declare -a arr='([0]="hah   a" [1]="hehe" [2]="hoho")'
```

We are using control character `\03` as output field separator and using same in `IFS` to make `read` split fields on `\03`.

---

Alternatively you can use `sed` instead of `awk` also:

```bash
IFS=$'\03' read -ra arr < <(sed 's/#\$/\x03/g' file)
```

---

Using a NUL byte with BASH ver 4+

```bash
readarray -d $'\0' arr < <(
awk -F'#\\$' -v OFS='\0' '{ORS=OFS; $1=$1} 1' file)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But with arrary, it's still the "space" missing issue -- you can check it with "echo ${arr[0]}" after the "declare -p arr" -- then you can see -- the arr[0] has only one space inside...

Comment: You must use `echo "${arr[0]}"` (note quotes around) to get correct output.

Comment: And still another small question -- your solution is still using single character as the IFS -- but for some multibyte language charset -- Japanese, Koren, and Chinese -- this control character is surely existing in the data content, So do you still have method to string separator? Thanks

Comment: Reason of using a control character was that there is less likelihood of presence of that character in actual strings. Most of the shell utilities are not Unicode compliant by default.

Comment: btw you can use NUL byte also e.g. `readarray -d $'\0' arr < <(awk -F'#\\$' -v OFS='\0' '{ORS=OFS; $1=$1} 1' file);`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

getVar(){ 
    if [ "$1" -eq 0 ]; then  
        awk -F'#\\$' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $(i)}' file.txt;
    else
        awk -F'#\\$' -v col="$1" '{printf $(col)}' file.txt;
    fi
} 

# assign variables
VAR1=$(getVar 1)
VAR2=$(getVar 2)
VAR3=$(getVar 3)
# using variables
echo "VAR1 ===${VAR1}==="
echo "VAR2 ===${VAR2}==="
echo "VAR3 ===${VAR3}==="
echo

# declare array
readarray -t my_array < <(getVar 0)
# dump
declare -p my_array|sed 's/declare -a //'
# using variables
echo "VAR1 ===${my_array[0]}==="
echo "VAR2 ===${my_array[1]}==="
echo "VAR3 ===${my_array[2]}==="
```

**output**

```
VAR1 ===hah   a===
VAR2 ===hehe===
VAR3 ===hoho===

my_array=([0]="hah   a" [1]="hehe" [2]="hoho")
VAR1 ===hah   a===
VAR2 ===hehe===
VAR3 ===hoho===
```

Comment: Thanks. But here is 1 question --  It looks you changed the delimiter from #$ to # only -- So it's still facing the same problem as anubhava's answer -- can't use multichar string as delimiter...Please have a look. thanks

Comment: @EisenWang sorry, thought something different. should now work with the "#$" delimiter